# Click "Tab" from a textbox to another textbox, The graphic disappeared

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a 2 textboxes, a Panel, in the panel i have a Graphic:

```
Graphics g=myPanel.CreateGraphics();
```

When I click "Tab" from the first textbox, the focus moves to the second textbox, my Graphic disappeared magically!

Comment: Mode code needed especially around the tab from first text box!!

Comment: I don't have code for "tab". I just drag the textboxes, drag the panel, and when i click "Tab" on the keyboard, the focus changes itself. but the graphic i drawed disappeared.

Comment: try overriding the OnPaintMethod() for Panel

Comment: So you're having problem with the Designer ?

Comment: Need more info :) show your code.

Comment: It is not magic.  **Never** use CreateGraphics(), whatever you draw will be overdrawn as soon as panel repaints itself.  It doesn't require anything more than minimizing the window and restoring it.

Use the panel's Paint event instead.